# How to put a command and phrase (message) in a same line in Java?

Tags: java, switch-statement

Wonder if it is possible to put a phrase right after the message command. After running the program it may look like so in the console:

```
command: message Result for Adam!
```

and then the phrase after the message command (Result for Adam!) will be shown in a frame. But the code I have i like so:

```
command: message
Result for Adam!
```

I have to press enter after the message command to write the phrase in a new line and then the message shows in a frame. How do you control the line breaks in switch statements?

```
switch (command)
            {
                case "add event":
                    break;      

                case "add participant":
                    break;

                case "add result":
                    break;

                case "message":
                    framedText.showMessage();                   
                    break;

                case "exit":
                    System.exit(0);

                default:
                    System.out.println("Wrong (type of) command. Try again.");      
            } 

.
.
.

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MessageFramer {

    private Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void showMessage() {
        String message = scan.nextLine();



}
```

Comment: `How do you control the line breaks in switch statements?` ... can you elaborate on this?

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You have used the wrong method for when assigning your scanner object to your string.

Instead of:

```
 public void showMessage() {
        String message = scan.nextLine();
}
```

Try:

```
 public void showMessage() {
        String message = scan.next();
}
```

For `nextLine()` method is one reason for line breaks in output.

Correspondingly, this is the same for the `print()` and `println()` methods.

**EDIT:** In the event of not having the enter key submit user input to display results on a newline, the suggestible mechanic is the carriage return: `"\r"`. Which returns to the line of the aforementioned user input.

Comment: What I believe you are trying to achieve includes concatenation. Put everything in one `println()` method.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this is not what I am meaning. I have to put a phrase right after the command message. The solution I have now i like have press enter after the message command to write a phrase.

Comment: What you want is a carriage return: `"\r"`. This will make everything be included on the same line.